# C# WCF JSON WebService to return mime-type image/png

Tags: c#, json, wcf, web-services, wcf-rest

I'm runnning a WCF webservice using JSON formatting as follows. My problem is that the response format is alowas Json or XML but for GetImage I would like to return the image as mime-type image-png. Any idea how to do this in WCF? Thanks in advance.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEditor
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetImage", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    byte[] GetImage();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetBounds", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
void GetBounds(out Rectangle bounds, out Point[] viewport);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `WebOperationContext.Current`
2. return `Stream`

Your method should be something like this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetImage", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public Stream GetImage()
{
    var m = new MemoryStream();
    //Fill m

    // very important!!! otherwise the client will receive content-length:0
    m.Position = 0;

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/png";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = m.Length;
    return m;
}
```

Comment: And how would you read the image on the other side? Block-wise with BeginRead? The following code throws an exception "parameter not valid"             `Stream data = client.GetImage();
            canvas.Image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(data);`

Comment: Similar to reading an image from a web site. Type its url to browser and see the result.

Comment: Even if I enabled the transport mode to Streamed or StreamedResponse, both on client and server I get an exception while reading the image. I'm still trying to figure out how to read the stream. Will post the code later.

Comment: I tried following [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/fetching-image-using-wcf-rest-service/) but even if I set the content-length, the client will see content-length:0

Comment: I changed your code above. You MUST reset the position of the memory stream to 0.